# How to echo a particular line alone to stdout from a script , if the script's stdout is redirected to a file during execution?

Tags: shell, scripting, stdout, file-descriptor, io-redirection

Consider ./my_script >/var/log/my_log

Single echo statement from this script alone must to go to stdout.

How could this be accomplished ?

Comment: What makes you prefer the most complex answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so we have some clever program

```
cat print2stdout 
#!/bin/sh

echo some words secret and sent to null

echo some words to stdout > /dev/fd/3
```

last line puts to echo to 3 file descriptor opened.

and when invoking we map 3 FD to stdout, then redirect stdout to file

the result looks like that:

```
./print2stdout 3>&1 >/dev/null  
some words to stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `/dev/tty` which points to your terminal emulator regardless of redirections.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo this line go to the possibly redirected stdout 
echo this line shows up on the screen > /dev/tty
```